# C++ Wrapper to GNU Readline

Tags: c++, static, readline

I am trying to write a c++ wrapper for GNU Readline to be able to easily use custom completion but came across a small problem and can't think of a solution(I am still new to c++).

```
class ReadLine {

public:

    ReadLine();
    ~ReadLine();

    std::string exec ();
    void enableHistory ();

private:
    std::vector<std::string> keywordList;
    bool history;

private:
    static char** my_completion (const char*, int, int);
    void* xmalloc (int);

    char* generator (const char*, int);
    char* dupstr (std::string);

};
```

cpp file:

```
std::string ReadLine::exec(){

    rl_attempted_completion_function = my_completion;

    std::string buf = "";

    buf = readline("Command>>");
    //enable auto-complete
    rl_bind_key('\t',rl_complete);

    if (buf[0]!=0)
        add_history(buf.c_str());

    return buf;
}




char** ReadLine::my_completion (const char* text, int start, int end) {


    char** matches;

    matches = NULL;

    if (start == 0) 
        matches = rl_completion_matches(text, my_generator);

    return matches;


}
```

My problem is the line

> matches = rl_completion_matches(text, my_generator)

It obviously throws an error: `call to non-static member function without an object argument` but I don't want to make the generator static and I can't find what arguments it should take, because I won't be able to access class members inside of it (I need keywordlist to generate keywords).

What would you suggest?

Comment: What is the motivation for `ReadLine::my_completion` being `static`?

Comment: @juanchopanza Line " rl_attempted_completion_function = my_completion;" again I am using it without argument, so it needs to be static. I know it is stupid to "solve" it in tht way but I dont know anything about C, so can't think of anything else.

Comment: Just so you know, as the `readline` function will block, you won't add the key binding until after the first call to `readline`.

Comment: @juanchopanza: This mixing C style function pointers with C++, which leads to needs for static members. And it's made more complex because there is no "context" sort of argument that we could pass in to hold `this`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg sorry I didn't get you, I had some problems with it but I thought it was because of generator. Could you please explain again... sorry I am not native english speaker

Comment: @khajvah: Joachim is saying your call to set the completion character happens AFTER the call to readline, which means it will have no effect on the current call to readline.

Comment: The first time you call your `exec` method, the binding of the tab-key to do completion will not be done until *after* you call the `readline` function. It will only be active after this first call to `exec`. Also, you only have to do the key binding *once* not every time you want to get input.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will put it in constructor :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not easy to solve this one in a good way, since the normal solution is to solve it by having a static wrapper function where you pass the pointer to the class in as an argument.

Someone else may be able to come up with something better, but I think the solution is to have a global variable that is a pointer to the current ReadLine class instance - this could be a stack, so you can push a new one onto it, and then pop it to get back to the old one when that's done.

In the simple case, you'd have something like this:

```
ReadLine *currenReadLine = 0;

.... 

std::string ReadLine::exec(){
   ... 
   currentReadLine = this;
}


// declared as static in the class.
char ** ReadLine::my_completion(...)
{
    return currentReadLine->actual_completion(...);
}
```

And a similar solution for the `my_generator`.

Comment: I will try to use this solution...(Also, it's good that this task is hard to do, as I felt stupid not being able to solve the problem)

Comment: Well, this solution is really not that hard - the hard part is a complete solution that doesn't use globals [and no "replacement for globals" that are just hiding the fact that it's a global variable - e.g. Singleton classes or static member variables].

Comment: This actually solves my problem(I can access class members), so for now, it is ok for me :)